# trouble sending data through Router

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, react-router

I am having issues sending data through my React Router
My data is coming from Wordpress REST API

First is my Nav function which reads from Wordpress, this is working

```
<Link to={menus[ky].slug} params={{ pageId: menus[ky].post_name }}>{menus[ky].title}</Link>
```

Next is my App function which uses MyRoutes function which dynamically creates the router
Then I have my Page compoent which I need to cathc the data from Nav.

basicallY I want to dynamically generate the URLs from Wordpress to keep SEO, then fetch the page HTML from REST API  (Not built yet, still trying to pass the pageId)

here is all the code

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Link,
    useLocation
} from 'react-router-dom';


function Nav() {
    
    const [menus, setMenus] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://dev.justinblayney.com/wp-json/menus/v1/menus/main-menu")
        .then(res => res.json())
    
        .then(json =>{
             setMenus(json.items)}
              )
        
       
         });
        
    
    return (
        
        <nav>
        <ul>
            {Object.keys(menus).map((ky, idx)=> (
             <li id={idx} key={idx}>
                <Link
                  to={{
                    pathname: menus[ky].slug,
                    state: {
                      pageId: menus[ky].post_name,
                    },
                  }}
                >
                  {menus[ky].title}
                </Link>
            </li>
        ))}
        </ul>
    </nav>
  
    );
}



function MyRoutes() {
    
    const [menus, setMenus] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://dev.justinblayney.com/wp-json/menus/v1/menus/main-menu")
        .then(res => res.json())
    
        .then(json =>{
             setMenus(json.items)}
              )
         });
        
    
    return (
        <>
            {Object.keys(menus).map((ky, idx)=> (
                <Route exact path={menus[ky].slug} component={Page}  key={idx} />
            ))} 
        </>
  
    );
}


class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            
     <Router> 
        <div className="App">
            <Header />      
            <Nav />
                <Route exact path='/' component={Page} />
                <MyRoutes />
                
            <Footer />
   
         </div>
      </Router> 
    
        );  
    }
}

export default App;
    
    
  
function Page() {
  const { state: { params: { pageId } } } = useLocation();
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      
    
      
      <h3>Requested page ID: {pageId}</h3>
      
      
     </div>
  );

}

export default Page;
```

Comment: Are you *actually* using react-router/react-router-dom? Or are you using Nextjs's navigation components? React-router-dom `Link` components don't accept a `params` prop. Please include a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code examples. It's not clear what package the `Link` and `Router` components are from and this directly affects how we can help you.

Comment: sorry about that, edited above

Comment: if react-router-dom cant accomplish this, what can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send data along with a route transition from a link using route state.

[Link to: object](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object)

> An object that can have any of the following properties:
>
> - pathname: A string representing the path to link to.
> - search: A string representation of query parameters.
> - hash: A hash to put in the URL, e.g. #a-hash.
> - state: State to persist to the location.

`state` is the property you are interested in.

Send the data you want the receiving `Route` and component to have on the `state` property.

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: menus[ky].slug,
    state: {
      params: {
        pageId: menus[ky].post_name,
      },
    },
  }}
>
  {menus[ky].title}
</Link>
```

To retrieve the route state it is accessible from [route props'](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) [location](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location) object.

```
location.state.params.pageId
```

There are two basic ways to access the `location` object

Via `props`

1. `this.props.location` (class-based component)
2. `props.location` (functional component)
3. Injected into props via the [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) HOC and available from 1 or 2

Via [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) react hook

1. `const { state: { params: { pageId } } } = useLocation();`

If you've nothing else to add between `state` and `pageId` then it likely makes more sense to drop the intermediate `params` property and just store `pageId`.

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: menus[ky].slug,
    state: {
      pageId: menus[ky].post_name,
    },
  }}
>
  {menus[ky].title}
</Link>
```

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation Drew, believe it or not I did read most of the documentation and tried that code the last few days (I'm, been struggling with this since Thursday).  I update my code above, but it still isnt working, I get no errors, my page compnent doesnt even seem to be loading as i dont get  <h3>Requested page ID: {pageId}</h3> displayed

Comment: @JustinBlayney Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue that we could live debug on? For simplicity you can mock the `fetch` for `menus` state in `Nav` (i.e. just set the initial state to what the response JSON *should* be).

Comment: hello, i did, I was able to add it all as the whole thing is quite simple so far... I have quite a few issues, the main one at this time is the Page component isn't loading dynamically.. I do not know if pageID is being passed...    If this was php, i would echo my code and check to see the problems, is their a way to do that with my react router code?  I hard coded a page ID into page function just to see if it worked..  Here is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-khorana-nw8xl?file=/src/App.js

Comment: it looks like Routes are not being rendered and passed from MyRoutes to APP.. If i manually code the Routes using the wordpress slug and the Page component it works

Comment: Im going to start a new thread you answerd the question I had and the issue ended up being something else. Thank you